# How to manage multiple repositories in a build inside TeamCity?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, teamcity, devops, continuous-delivery

I was assigned to implement a CI / CD process (Using TeamCity) in a project in my company.

The point is that the project is distributed in different repositories (One for the framework, one for the base application and two for project-specific issues)

If I were to assemble this project now, I should first clone the framework, then clone the other repositories and manually move them to their proper folders.

The project in its "final form" has a folder structure similar to this:

```
BigProject/
├── Framework (Repository)/
│   ├── bin/
│   ├── obj/
│   ├── Application/
│        ├── BaseApplication (Repository)/
│            ├── Foo/
│            ├── Bar/
│            ├── Project-Specific-1 (Respository)/
│            ├── Project-Specific-2 (Respository)/
```

In TeamCity, I set up all VCS Roots for the four repositories and edited the Checkout Rules to make it all work.

For example, I set the Checkout Rule of my BaseApplication to look like this:

```
+:.=>./Framework/Application/
```

As I understand it, this command should copy all contents of the BaseApplication repository to the directory ./Framework/Application/ .

The problem is that when I run the build I get the following error:

```
stderr: The 'https: //me@myvcs.com/xx/xx/BaseApplication.git' repository has a submodule in the 'xx' commit to the 'Project-Specific-1' path, but has not .gitmodules configuration in the root directory
exit code: 1
```

I do not understand why this error is happening. Did I go wrong setting up Checkout Rules? Is TeamCity trying to build the project before doing the necessary checkouts? Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make this work?

A note, I cannot configure .gitmodules for this project because I believe that .gitmodules should be in the framework repository and the framework is used in other projects.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to checkout a repository within another repositories structure. Git itself is complaining about this and not TeamCity. You could change the general directory structure so that the application isn't inside the framework anymore.

```
BigProject/
├── Framework (Repository)/
│   ├── bin/
│   ├── obj/
├── BaseApplication (Repository)/
│   ├── Foo/
│   ├── Bar/
├── Project-Specific-1 (Respository)/
├── Project-Specific-2 (Respository)/
```

Comment: You could also provide a `.gitmodules` ([reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules)). 

But i'd got the route that you suggested and seperate it into multiple repositories side by side.